# Query with variables RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r

I tried this script to select a field in the table using RMySQL:

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="***", user='***',host='***')
a<-29553
b<-31097
c<-'chr1'
s<-'+'
res<-dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT name FROM wgEncodeGencodeBasicV27 WHERE 
chrom=c AND strand=s AND txStart=a AND txEnd=b")
```

but it returns the error: “Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'”.
Why? How can I correct the script?

Comment: Will you clarify what "doesn't work" means? Do you get an error, and if so what is it?

Comment: FYI, you should **not** include real login info in your question. Your server could be compromised.

Comment: Along with what @SloanThrasher said, you should change your password asap.

Comment: The error message is: “Unknown column “c” in where clause”

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea is that you can prepare your `query` dynamically with helps of the variables. This takes away needs to send variables as parameter separately. `sprintf` fits nicely for this purpose.

Taking the case from `OP`. The approach should be:

```
#Variables to be used in query
a<-29553
b<-31097
c<-'chr1'
s<-'+'

library(RMySQL)

mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="***", user='***',host='***')

#Prepare a query format string with place holders for variables. 
queryFormat <- "SELECT name FROM wgEncodeGencodeBasicV27 
WHERE chrom=`%s` AND strand=`%s` AND txStart=%d AND txEnd=%d"

#Use sprintf to prepare the query
query <- sprintf(queryFormat, c, s, a, b)

res<-dbSendQuery(mydb, query)

#The final query which has been send to Database:
#[1] "SELECT name FROM wgEncodeGencodeBasicV27 
# WHERE chrom=`chr1` AND strand=`+` AND txStart=29553 AND txEnd=31097"
```